# How can I access Column names in datagrid programatically at run-time in C#

Tags: c#, datagrid, bindingsource

**Background to the Question**

Working in C#

I have a datagridview that is populated by a generic db method that exposes a data adapter and a binding source. The binding source is the datasource for the datagrid.

e.g.  dgrid.DataSource=bindingSource;

I use the same generic db method to retrieve data from multiple tables and the same datagrid to display the data retrieved - so by varying the sqlcommand the datagrid display data from any specified db table on a SINGLE form using a SINGLE datagrid.

This reusable method allows me to displays data from any table in a single datagrid on a single form.

**Logical Flow**

Data from DB-->Assigned To BindingSource-->Assigned To DataGrid

**The QUESTION**

Typically I would reorder the columns on the datagrid using the 'Edit Columns' dialog but the  datagridview in this case only exists at run-time.

Since the datagrid column names are not known until runtime ie until the binding source is invoked **how do I programmatically access the column names**, **once the binding is complete,** in order to reorder the columns and to facilitate further data manipulation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just to know the column name after binding has been done, you can use :

`GridView1.Columns[Index].HeaderText`

Comment: Many thanks - got it working using your hint - used this code  dgShow.Columns["ColName"].DisplayIndex = 0;